# How can I run a command line process that requires AD authentication from a .NET web service?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, web-services, impersonation

This is almost identical to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350278/process-start-and-impersonation) asked by another user, and is the sequel to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847256/why-cant-my-asp-net-web-service-kick-off-a-process-but-my-net-console-app-can) I asked previously.

Basically, my company recently bought Tidal Scheduler. We need to launch jobs ad hoc from other process, e.g.: BizTalk, .NET web apps, etc. Our plan was to wrap a .net web service around the C++ API. That is apparently going away version.next, so we are instead trying to wrap a .net web service around their command line interface.

The client requires Active Directory authentication. Using pretty much every method below for impersonation we have been unable to successfully call the CLI from our .net web service.  From what I read in the question linked above, we are trying to impersonate a user with more rights than the ASPNET account, and this causes a security hole.

Is there a better way to do this? Is there a way to make it work with the road we have already traveled?  Any help is appreciated, we have sunk way to much time into this.

Side note: we did make this happen using [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx), but at this point it's such a huge hack-around (it's a big enough hack-around as it is) that we would very much prefer not to use this in our environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible method would be to run the web service in an App Pool that has the credentials of the user you need to impersonate.  (This is assuming the authentication is the result of trying the operation and failing as the account running the current web service....if it requires authentication even when running as the user you're impersonating, you're out of luck.)

The impersonated user will need to be a member of the IIS_WPG group on the box the web service is running under.  It may also need a few local permissions.  Just make sure the user you are impersonating as very limited rights on the box itself.

Comment: You sir, are my hero.  After struggling impersonation of every variety, this simple change fixed everything. I thank you.

Comment: Ah I'm glad it worked out for you.  I've used this method for SSPI DB connections before, and your issue seemed similar.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you need is a windows service that has your credentials.  Then your web service can call your WIndows Service to execute whatever it is you want to do.  A Windows Service is a project template in Visual Studio and the docs on MSDN are very straightforward.